# How Do I install specific version of monit on redhat linux

Tags: redhat, yum, monit

"Yum install monit" command by default will install 5.14 version. But Monit has released till 5.20 version

I tried with the below command for available packages

```
sudo yum --showduplicates list monit | expand
```

It shows up only one available package
Available Packages
monit.x86_64                                 5.14-1.el6

Are there any other option apart from manually downloading the tar using wget command and then installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be an RPM on the rpmforge/repoforge repos although these are presently down.

I believe these might resurface (based on this https://github.com/repoforge/rpms/issues/375) but in the mean time unless you want to build your own RPM for it you could grab this from a mirror.

Such as:

```
yum install https://www.insaneworks.co.jp/pub/el6/RPMS/x86_64/monit-5.20.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks Scott-Mc. I tried with the above command. but it failed with the below error.      Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-AdrTM1/monit-5.20.0-2.3.1.ppc64.rpm: monit-5.20.0-2.3.1.ppc64
Cannot add package ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/opensuse/ports/update/13.2/ppc64/monit-5.20.0-2.3.1.ppc64.rpm to transaction. Not a compatible architecture: ppc64
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: That looks like a different package to the one I mentioned.   Did you try the one I mentioned which was for EL6 and x86_64.  The one you seemed to have tried to install looks to be a different one (opensuse + ppc64 arch).

Comment: I tried your command and I was able to install it but it has older version of monit(monit 5.2), and I would like to install latest monit version 20.0, which I could not find from the list.

Comment: Ah use this one for the 5.20 version
yum install https://www.insaneworks.co.jp/pub/el6/RPMS/x86_64/monit-5.20.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm